# Whats the difference between sample size and sampling size?

Tags: r, sampling, central-limit-theorem

I am currently studying a r code that's used for verifying the CLT and in that function, there are three inputs. First is n which is the number of observations second is a parameter for a geometric distribution and the third is the sam[ling size which I can't make sense of.

Comment: My guess they are usually used to mean the same thing and [*sample size* is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sample+size%2Csampling+size&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csample%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csampling%20size%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: In addition to @Henry's comment, it seems that *sampling size* is only the name of a variable so I wouldn't read too much into it. Although one may wonder about the difference with the first parameter (number of observations). It would help if you posted the actual code...

Comment: @dariober If you were trying to illustrate the CLT through simulation you might take the average of $n$ random variables $k$ times and look at the empirical distribution of the $k$ averages.  Which of $n$ and $k$ is the number of observations and which the sample size is not immediately obvious to me.